# Why does File.listFiles() throws NullPointerException on some devices?

Tags: android-file

Please pay attention to all the tests in the following code:

```
File folder = new File(sFolderPath);
if (folder == null) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    if (folder.exists()) {
        File[] flist = folder.listFiles();
    }
}
```

folder.listFiles() throws the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

It rarely happens.  I am wondering how this can be possible after passing the tests of null and existence.

Comment: I don't know if this is your specific problem, but there's a race condition in your code. Some other code (yours if multithreaded or someone else's in any case) could delete the folder between the `.exists()` check and the call to `.listFiles`. Use `try/catch` instead. This is a common anti-pattern in dealing with files on all platforms/languages.

Comment: @JaredSmith  thank you for the tip.  Fortunately, we have found a user who  can reproduce this error reliably on his device (I will try to find the model).  The folder is a unique one for the app, and it is rarely used. It is unlikely for race condition to occur.